# AutoMapper and Linq expression

Tags: lambda, automapper

I am exposing the Dto generated from AutoMapper to my WCF services.
I would like to offer something like that from WCF:
IList GetPersonByQuery(Expression> predicate);
Unfortunately I need back an expression tree of Person as my DAL doesn't know the DTO.
I am trying this wihtout success:

```
        var func = new Func<Person, bool>(x => x.FirstName.Contains("John"));
        var funcDto = Mapper.Map<Func<Person, bool>, Func<PersonDto, bool>>(func);
        Console.WriteLine(func.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(funcDto.ToString());
```

THe error that I get is:

```
----> System.ArgumentException : Type 'System.Func`2[TestAutoMapper.PersonDto,System.Boolean]' does not have a default constructor
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper does not support mapping to/from expressions or delegates.  If you tried to write that mapping by hand, I think you'd see why :)

Comment: Yeah I saw it, unfortunately ... :-)
Thanks anyway